# Kubernetes nginx ingress controller special rewrite rules

Tags: nginx-ingress

I have nginx configuration something like that:

```
server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  server_name   app.example.com;
  include       common.conf;
  include       ssl.conf;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_logging;

  location /_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://backend-name;
    # For testing cache - remove before deploying to production
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
  }

  location /static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://backend-name;
    # For testing cache - remove before deploying to production
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
  }

  location / {
    rewrite /(.*) /apppath/$1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://backend-name;
    include     common_location.conf;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_logging;
  }
}
```

so I need redirect all URL that **not started** from `/_next/static` and `/static` to `/apppath/$1` of backend and `/_next/static` and `/static` redirect to the / of backend.

**Is it possible to do the same using just nginx ingress controller?**

Thank you

Comment: Are you aware of the [`configuration-snippet:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation? or, perhaps, [the `server-snippet:` ConfigMap key](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-snippet)?

Comment: @mdaniel yes, i've tried but have an errors about host name not found...

Comment: What does your ingress configuration look like?

Comment: it fixed now. it is possible to add custom "location" entries, but also need to add whole lua  content from regular session.

Comment: @AndriiPetrenko , please consider adding your solution as an answer,  so the question won't be orpaned.